# How do I return a list of blobs in a container within my ASP.NET Core application?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to cleanly wire up a method to fetch a list of blobs within a specified container and return it to a view in my ASP.NET Core application.  Looking at the Microsoft documentation I can't see any examples of this being done save a console app but that's causing me more confusion over the implementation.

Here is the code, starting with the `Edit` method of my `HomeController`.  This is simple enough, `id` is passed in and data is returned, that Id is passed to the `BlobStorageService` `ListBlobsAsync` method to identify the correct container for all the files.

**HomeController/Edit**

```
[HttpGet]        
public IActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var car = _carService.GetCar(id);
    BlobStorageService objBlob = new BlobStorageService(accessKey);
    objBlob.ListBlobsAsync(car.Id.ToString());
    return View(car);
}
```

Here is my `BlobStorageService.cs`

**BlobStorageService**

```
public async void ListBlobsAsync(string id)
{
    //Folder Structure /uploads/car/<id>/contents
    string strContainerName = "uploads";
    string pathPrefix = "car";

    CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(accessKey);
    CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

    CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(strContainerName);                        
    CloudBlobDirectory blobDirectory = cloudBlobContainer.GetDirectoryReference(pathPrefix);
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = blobDirectory.GetBlockBlobReference(id);

    await blockBlob.DownloadBlockListAsync();
}
```

At this point I'm stuck, is this approach correct for listing the contents of my defined directory and if so, how do I then return this to the view to be used?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage package. If you can use `Azure.Storage.Blobs` package then try below code.

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static string connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=storage******c9709;AccountKey=v**************************************;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
        static string container = "azure-webjobs-hosts";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Get a reference to a container named "sample-container" and then create it
            BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, container);
            blobContainerClient.CreateIfNotExists();
            Console.WriteLine("Listing blobs...");
            // List all blobs in the container
            var blobs = blobContainerClient.GetBlobs();
            foreach (BlobItem blobItem in blobs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t" + blobItem.Name);
            }            
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

You can also download the content of blob, Check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet#list-the-blobs-in-a-container)